# c# print asterisk pyramid using recursion

Tags: c#, visual-studio, recursion, a-star

i was given a question witch is :
write a function that get n number(integer),
the program will print an asterisk  * pyramid by the height of n number..
in the first line the function will print one "*",
and the next line it will print 2 more * and so on.
that mean if i input 4, the result needs to looks like this, 
but the pyramid way:

```
   *

  ***

 *****

*******
```

I must write the program the recursion way, without any loop..
so at first i wrote this code, that input a height and send a number into a function that print the pattern, i know i need to do another function that print the spaces but i got confused understanding how to do it the recursion way..

```
static void trianglePattern(int hight, int n)
    {
        if(n == 0)
        {
            return;
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
        trianglePattern(hight - 1, n + 1 * 2); 
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int hight;
        Console.WriteLine("enter hight:");
        hight = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        trianglePattern(hight, 1);
    }
```

thanks for the help

Comment: `hight` should be spelled as `height`

Comment: @Luuk While that may be true, it brings him nowhere nearer an actual solution or answer.

Comment: Here's some tips on how to solve this: First, create a method or a piece of code that can output 1 line from that triangle. In other words, feed that method (or code) a number, like 4, and it prints one line containing 4 asterixes, ie. `****`. Then, ignore this method/code for a bit, and create a recursive method that counts from 1 up to N, where N is that height, and just outputs that number. Then, combine the two so that instead of outputting the number directly, call the first method from the second method.

Comment: It might help to write it using a loop first, so that you know you understand how to get the triangle part working, and then rewrite it to a recursive solution.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen: I was just fooling, of course, but yesterday i did search half an hour for a typo, the typo was `heigth` in stead of `height`  

Comment: A couple of things... 1) you can construct a string from a `char` and a repeat count (no loops required), 2) it may be easier to draw the pyramid upside down (recursively) at first (write out the longest line, then have that call itself to write out the line somewhat shorter, etc.  Once you get that working, think about inverting the logic.  May I just think upside down

Comment: i've writen the code with loops of course, but im still having diffucult understanding the recursion way

Comment: n is never going to be zero since it only grows bigger.  It looks like `if (n == 0)` should be `if (hight == 0)`  Of course, you are missing code that prints the number of stars.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the below code it should do what you want,

```
  // function to print a row 
                public static void printn(int num) 
                { 
                // base case 
                if (num == 0) 
                return; 
                Console.Write("*"); 

                // recursively calling printn() 
                printn(num - 1); 
                } 

// function to print the pattern 
                public static void pattern(int n, int i) 
                { 
                // base case 
                if (n == 0) 
                    return; 
                printn(i); 
                Console.WriteLine(); 

                // recursively calling pattern() 
                pattern(n - 1, i + 1); 
                }
```

and your main should be something like this:

```
int n = 5; // and the could be a user input using console.readLine() 
pattern(n, 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Every next line should have one space less than the previous line.

If you have 4 lines, the last line has 0 spaces, so the first line has 4 spaces.